# Getting the same value when estimating the mean across different categories

Tags: r, group-by, mean

I am trying to estimate the mean value of a lab test reading *igg1_norm* across different categories of a variable *type* (5 categories).

```
    db <- forg %>% 
  group_by(forg$type)%>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE),sd=sd(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE),lower = mean(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE) - sd(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE), upper = mean(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE) + sd(forg$igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE))
```

My data looks like as per below

```
 cowidfarm type  time_num igg1_norm  igg2_norm 
   <chr>     <fct> <fct>    <labelled> <labelled>
 1 LM1047    3     1        0.1080482  0.4526854 
 2 LM1047    3     2        0.1833975  0.6029548 
 3 LM1047    3     3        0.1704118  0.5394913 
 4 LM1050    1     1        0.2883397  0.4347826 
 5 LM1050    1     2        0.1453905  0.5655340 
 6 LM1050    1     3        0.3302948  0.4962779 
 7 LM1134    3     1        0.4498922  0.6672078 
 8 LM1134    3     2        0.2641302  0.6204986 
 9 LM1134    3     3        0.3207913  0.5074442 
10 LM1221    3     1        1.2184955  0.8653846
```

I get no errors when running the code but the output is odd as I get only one value when I was expecting 5 values (one for each category).

```
       mean        sd      lower     upper
1 0.4046562 0.3239133 0.08074287 0.7285695
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong? Any help is dearly appreciated

Comment: Remove all the `forg$` from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Stefan. However it didn't produce any change. I am still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you tried but when I remove `forg$` from your code I get:

```r
library(dplyr)

forg %>% 
  group_by(type)%>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE),sd=sd(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE),
            lower = mean(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE) - sd(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE), 
            upper = mean(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE) + sd(igg1_norm, na.rm=TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>    type  mean     sd   lower upper
#> * <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.255 0.0969 0.158   0.352
#> 2     3 0.388 0.383  0.00469 0.771
```

**DATA**

```
forg <- read.table(text = "cowidfarm type  time_num igg1_norm  igg2_norm 
  1 LM1047    3     1        0.1080482  0.4526854 
2 LM1047    3     2        0.1833975  0.6029548 
3 LM1047    3     3        0.1704118  0.5394913 
4 LM1050    1     1        0.2883397  0.4347826 
5 LM1050    1     2        0.1453905  0.5655340 
6 LM1050    1     3        0.3302948  0.4962779 
7 LM1134    3     1        0.4498922  0.6672078 
8 LM1134    3     2        0.2641302  0.6204986 
9 LM1134    3     3        0.3207913  0.5074442 
10 LM1221    3     1        1.2184955  0.8653846 ", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Many thanks Stefan. I was getting the same error even when copy pasting your code to make sure I wasn't doing any typos. So I decided to go back to the markdown and simplify things, namely the amount of functions I was loading with library(). And it worked :) It must have been some sort of conflict between the different functions I had loaded. Many thanks for your help!